# rails 3 actionmailer cannot send email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am following [Ryan Bates's tutorial on Rails 3 ActionMailer](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3). I generate the mailer in terminal and then establish a setup_mail.rb under config/initializers. I keyed in the following code:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings={
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domail               => "gmail.com",
  :user_name            => "my_account_at_gmail",
  :password             => "my_password",
  :authentication       => "plain"  ,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

My user_mailer.rb file goes like:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "my_account_at_gmail@gmail.com"

  def registration_confirmation(user)
    mail(:to => user.email,:subject => "registered")
  end
end
```

I tested in rails console:
u=User.first
UserMailer.registration_confirmation(u).deliver

it displays:

```
 #<Mail::Message:2194479560, Multipart: false, Headers: <Date: Sat, 26 Feb 2011 14:42:06 +0800>, <From: my_account_at_gmail@gmail.com>, <To: some_account@gmail.com>, <Message-ID: <some_number@My-MacBook-Pro.local.mail>>, <Subject: registered>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: text/plain>, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit>>
```

BUT I never received the email here... Why? How can I solve this? I guess it is some problem on send_mail.rb file..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's a copy/paste of your `send_mail.rb`, there is a spelling error in `:domain` (you have `:domail`) which may or may not be causing the issue.

If that doesn't work, try the following:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp # be sure to choose SMTP delivery
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :tls => true,
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "gmail.com",
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name => "my_account_at_gmail@gmail.com", # use full email address here
  :password => "password"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, it has been been suggested in the [Action Mailer Rails Edge Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)
to put the email configuration in the appropriate .rb file in your config/environments directory.  For me, I put the following in config/environments/development.rb to get emails sent using gmail's SMTP server:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true #useful to have to debug
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true #default value
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp #default value

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => "yourdomain.com",
    :user_name => "username@yourdomain.com",
    :password => "yourpassword",
    :authentication => :login, #or can use "plain"
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```